# Formatting Phone Number by adding zeros to the left

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have phone numbers like this :

> 452341
>
> 12
>
> 45789632

Is there a way i can format them like this way :

> 00452341
>
> 00000012
>
> 45789632

Comment: Of course there is. Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: How do you declare the variable that stores the phonenumber? Is it an integer or a string? The answer is different

Comment: the variable is an integer

Comment: If you're storing phone numbers as integers, *that* should be the problem you fix. They're not really numbers. You don't perform mathematics with them. In reality, they're strings. That just happen to be composed of digits.

Comment: If number is integer then you should have selected Ikram's answer. Ashkan's solution needs a conversion to string before padding. Later gives you intended result during conversion.

Comment: Integer class has the tostring method since it inherits from the Object class,

Comment: but what i dont understand is how some people react with such questions with downvotes and some negatives comments, my question was clear, ive tried to look up if there is a similar questions in this site but in vain, the only possible duplicate is a little different because it does not contains the word "phonenumber" but it leads to the same answer. Besides you cannot delete your own question it says : "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead.", all you can do, is watch yourself being humiliated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cam use Padding:

```
Number.PadLeft(length, '0');
```

For example:

```
string num = "1234";
num.PadLeft(10, '0');
```

The result will be 0000001234

Answer (score 4):

```
ToString("D8")
```

Here - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString)  - Decimal ("D") Format Specifier

**NOTE:**

`PadLeft(length, '0');` does not work for **negative numbers**

**Ex**: `(-1).Padleft(5, '0') --> 000-1`

Answer (score 3):

Use format with leading zeroes (Example for 8 symbols in number):

```
452341.ToString("D8");
```

if  you have already strign use solution of Ashkan:

```
"452341".PadLeft(8, '0');
```